# Is "at all" necessary in the following sentence?

Tags: phrases, sentence

> My body was totally anesthetized at the time. It was a miracle I had
>   managed to get an erection **at all**.

Is the *at all* at the end neccesary?

Comment: *At all* is mostly **not** necessary in *any* sentence. However, it may add to the meaning, shift the emphasis, change the tone, or just give it a flair. In the above sentence, it makes **all** the difference.

Answer (score 2):

As Kris mentions, a lot of words are not necessary in a sentence, but they are there because they give meaning to the sentence. For example, the word "totally" is not necessary in your sentence either.

So, the question really is, what does "at all" mean in this sentence?

It is an idiomatic expression that indicates that something that was unlikely happened, and it especially conveys the idea that whatever happened might be seen as a normal, not unlikely event by whoever you are addressing.

An example.
Let's say the weather is terrible. It is snowing, there's a storm.

> The weather is terrible. It's a miracle I managed to get to work today.

Here, I simply state two facts: the weather is bad, and getting to work was a miraculous feat.

Now let's change the context. After I got to work, my manager scolds me for being late. My reply might well be:

> Have you seen the weather? It's a miracle I managed to get here at all!

My manager scolds me for being late, assuming that getting to work *on time* is a normal thing. However, being *on time* was not even an issue for me on this particular day. My problem was getting to work, anyway and at any time.

Now in your example phrase, although some context is missing, I assume that the mentioned erection plays some role, and someone might have commented on its quality or duration or what have you.
Here the assumption seems to be that getting an erection, like coming to work, is a very normal thing, and should not require much special effort.

By adding "at all" to the sentence, the speaker indicates that actually the quality of said erection is hardly something to criticize, because under the circumstances, it is already quite surprise there was any erection to start with.

Now, what would the sentence mean without "at all"?

> My body was totally anesthetized at the time. It was a miracle I had managed to get an erection.

This gives the impression that the speaker felt the need to try and get an erection, and to his own surprise, he managed to do so. Especially without further context, it is very hard to imagine any logical connection between the anesthetized body and the ability to get an erection and the sentence evokes a weird feeling in the reader (at least to me, it really sounds strange).

> My body was totally anesthetized at the time. It was a miracle I had managed to get an erection at all.

For some reason the speaker now feels the need to defend the quality(?) of his erection, and he explains he was, under the circumstances, not even expecting to get *any* kind of erection in the first place.
Admittedly, this does not immediately evoke a very common or recognizable situation to me either, but at least there is a clearer connection between the two sentences and I can make at least *some* guess as to the context.

So yes, in this case the addition of **at all** makes **all** the difference :)

Comment: 1 up from me, not hard at all.